# Receiving data from BLE in linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with bluetooth low-energy and am sending a characteristics with >70 bytes of data.

I am facing problem in receiving >20 bytes of data in Linux.

Is it possible to increase the MTU size in Linux?

Comment: What language are you coding in? What Linux Distro are you using? Could you provide the code you are using? See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help on how to ask a good question.

Comment: BLE is limited to 20 bytes. You wil need to split your data into chunks